# Bigcommerce Pagination in php

Tags: php, pagination, bigcommerce

i hope all are doing well, I am working on Bigcommerce API integration with PHP, as API fetches 50 records per page, but what i want is it starts fetching all records 50 and then from next page store it in an array and then that data should be dropped to the database, i am confused with how to pass current page id to the api

```
self::set_config($channel);
        $page  = 1;
        $url=self::$current_channel->api_url."v3/catalog/products?page=$page";
        $headers = self::getHeader($channel);
        $body = '';
        $response=self::make_api_request($url,$body,"GET",$headers);
//        echo "<pre>";
//        print_r($response->meta->pagination->total);
//        echo "</pre>";
//        exit;
        if(isset($response->data)) {
            foreach ($response->data as $item) {
                $record = self::get_product_detail($channel,$item->id); // get detail from api
                $record = isset($record->data[0]) ? $record->data[0] : NULL;
                if ($record)
                {
                    $mappedItems = [
                        'parent_sku_id' => null,
                        'sku' => $record->id,
                        'channel_sku' => $record->sku,
                        'variation_id' => $record->option_set_id,
                        'name' => $record->name,
                        'ean' => $record->upc, //$data->mpn, $data->gtin
                        'price' => $record->price,
                        'stock_qty' => isset($record->inventory_level) ? $record->inventory_level : null,
                        'channel_id' => self::$current_channel->id,
                        'is_live' => isset($record->is_visible) ? $record->is_visible : "1",
                        'type1' => 'main_product',
                    ];
                    $parent_sku_id = self::save_channel_products((object)$mappedItems); // will return product id from products table
                    $headers = self::getHeader($channel);

                    $url=self::$current_channel->api_url."v3/catalog/products/$item->id/variants";
                    $server_output = self::make_api_request($url,$body,"GET",$headers);

                    if ($parent_sku_id && isset($record->option_set_id)) {
                        foreach ($server_output->data as $variation) {
                            $mappedItems = [
                                'parent_sku_id' => $parent_sku_id,
                                'sku' => $variation->sku_id,
                                //'sku' => $variation->product_id,
                                'channel_sku' => $variation->sku,
                                // 'variation_id' => $variation->sku_id,
                                'variation_id' => $variation->id,
                                'name' => $record->name,
                                'ean' => $variation->upc, //$variation->mpn, $variation->gtin
                                'price' => $variation->calculated_price,
                                'stock_qty' => isset($variation->inventory_level) ? $variation->inventory_level : null,
                                'channel_id' => self::$current_channel->id,
                                'is_live' => isset($record->is_visible) ? $record->is_visible : "1",
                                'type1' => 'variation',
                            ];
                            //echo '<pre>';print_r($new_item);die;

                           // self::save_channel_products((object)$mappedItems);
                            if(isset($response->meta->pagination->total))
                            {
                                self:: $products_fetched = self:: $products_fetched + 50; // for offset

                                if($response->meta->pagination->total > self:: $products_fetched)
                                {
                                    $lim=($response->meta->pagination->total - self:: $products_fetched);
                                    $lim= $lim > 50 ? 50:$lim;
                                    //self:: channelProducts(null,self:: $products_fetched ,$lim);
                                }
                                    echo $page = $response->meta->pagination->current_page;
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }


I am looking forward for help with php? i am little confused how to set per page request in api, every time it fetches same records in api i want to make it as per pagination changes
```

Answer (score 1):

you can send a key from url with get method ex: p=1 
and replace this code : `$page  = 1;` with :

```
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 1;
```